# Put all explode arrays to one string

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

let's say I have a string called `str`, I dont know how long is that.
characters in the string are separated by '-' after each 16th character.
Now i called function like `$ex = explode('-', $str);`.
Now it is in array. I have changed  some chracters in array. for example `$ex[0][0] = 'a';`
Now I want to connect that changed arrays back to variable `$str2`.
Something like `$str2 = $ex[0].ex[1]` but I don't know how long is that array.
Do you know how?

IF you didnt understand my explaination, tell me.

Thank you really much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want implode:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Example:

```
$str2 = implode('', $ex);
```

Comment: I was lookin on that few seconds ago, but I didn't understand what it does.
Well Im not good in English.
SO thank you really much

Comment: `$str2 = implode('', $ex);` should do it

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$str2 = implode('-', $ex);
```

This will take all of the elements of `$ex` and connect them into one string with the first parameter between each element. In this case: `-`.

If you don't want them to be connected by anything, then you can just do:

```
$str2 = implode($ex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [foreach](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). Foreach allows you to run through the array and automatically stop when the end has been reached.

An example would be:

```
foreach ($ex as $e) {
  $str2 .= $e;
}
```